# layout multiscreen

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

how to make a lenearLayout that contains 3 ImageViews of different size these images are on multiscreen but if I test my application on smartphones on different smartphone there is an image that does not appear

Here is the image:

[image]

...and here is the code that I use:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBleu"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tableLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/tooll" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/logofi15" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/squarem"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) or [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Comment: thinks.. screen problem

Comment: Your requirement is that attached image?

Comment: do you have multiple drawable folder with same image?

Comment: yes .Image hdpi,ldpi,...,xxxhdpi

Comment: so dont hard code  width and hight instead use wrap_content